# Why does gradle say that it cannot resolve "com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1"?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am building an app called Shaking. Today I added some button libraries to the project, namely:

Bootstrap Buttons: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/65

Flat Buttons: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/68

I added the following in the `dependencies` block of `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.1' //This is the bootstrap library
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5' //This is the flat buttons library
```

just like the webpages above have said.

Then an error pops up that says:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1

After some time, I figured out that the bootstrap buttons library is causing the problem because if I comment the line out, no errors!

I tried closing Android Studio and opening it again and cleaning the project, rebuilding... It all did not work.

Then I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702031/cannot-resolve-symbol-upon-support-library-version-change)
I thought the problems that I am having is quite similar to that so I followed the steps suggested by the second answer. This time, another error occurred:

> Error:failed to find target android-23 : C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

I think I do not have SDK 23 installed.

I really want to know why this happens and how can I fix it!

Comment: can you able to cross check your library gradile and app gradile that both compile version are same ?

Comment: @Sree What is "library gradle"? You mean the one that says "build,gradle (Project: Shaking)"?

Comment: yes, both your app and library will have a gradle file

Comment: I cannot find a compile version in my library gradle! Sorry, but I really don't understand these gradle thingys. @Sree

Comment: Did you update your sdk manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is build.gradle of com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.1:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'push.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode = Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE)
        versionName = VERSION_NAME
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

You can see that compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'.

Make sure that you have install android support library 23.1.1:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! The library requires the support library to work properly, but I don't have it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In build.grade module app add this:

implementation group: 'com.beardedhen', name: 'androidbootstrap', version: '2.3.2'